# Why doesn't Collections.copy increase the size of the destination?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm using the following code:

```
List<Object> dest = new LinkedList<Object>();
Collections.copy(oldList, src);
```

When i execute the code, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
    at java.util.Collections.copy(Collections.java:589)
```

I know how to fix that, but what i don't understand is:

**When i add elements manually, the list would increase the capacity automaticly. Why can't Collections#copy do that?**

Answer (score 4):

As StinePike already said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986805 : That's how it is implemented. It is just a convenience method that you can use instead of a for-loop like

```
for (int i=0; i<src.size(); i++)
{
    dst.set(i, src.get(i));
}
```

Regarding your question about the automatic size increase: It sounds as if you are actually looking for something like `Collection#addAll(Collection)` - so in this case

```
dest.addAll(src);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this is how it is implemented. If you see the source code of this [method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.copy%28java.util.List,java.util.List%29) you will see that

```
 if (srcSize > dest.size())
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");
```

So if you want to implement autoincrement, Then write your own method.

Comment: but why did they do that? this is not really a satisfiing answer. i see no benefit

Comment: It is a correct answer. The method is called copy and does what it is specified in the documentation: it copies the elements. There is nowhere a reference to a modification of the destination.

Comment: No, this answer is strictly speaking not correct. The behaviour is there because that's how the method is defined in the API documentation. Not because some vendor decided to put a few lines of code in an arbitrary implementation of a JVM.

Comment: if you read the first line of my answer .. Because this is how it is implemented... i pasted this implementation just for showing one implementation .... Thanks for the downvoting anyways (y)

Comment: i just want to say that I did not downvote! the answer is still correct but as i said not satisfying me

Comment: @StinePike: I read the first line of your answer and that's exactly the line I'm criticising. The behaviour Phillip sees is defined in the API documentation. As I said, looking at an arbitrary implementation of the API and deducting any assumptions on what the method does or is supposed to do is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collections#copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) is a utility method, that is intended to work for any `List`. This method is intended to just re-use the existing array and not allocate any memory. So, this might be efficient, else you might anyway use the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor, which would do the expansion job for you. The fact that the size constraint, and expansion is only related to `ArrayList` can also be a reason, not to add this behaviour to the method. That would just be extra code for the sake of just a particular `List` implementation. That is not how programming to interface works.

And since it is clearly mentioned in the docs, they would expect you to follow it.

Comment: The `List` interface has the methods `add` and `addAll` to expand the list.

Comment: @jarnbjo what rohit means are methods to expand the size, but leave the content unaffected

Comment: @jarnbjo Well, I didn't meant that really. But still have updated the answer. The point is there is no correct answer for this.

Comment: @PhillipSander: That might be what he means, but why should that be relevant in this case? If the copy method would expand the target list to fit the entire source list, it could simply have done that by adding the extra elements with the `add` method instead of replacing them with `set`.

Comment: @jarnbjo Updated the answer with some sensible answer. Might give a look.

Comment: @jarnbjo But `add()` method would not do that same thing as `set()` method. `add()` adds at the end. That's the difference. Had it used that, the `dest` list would not have been same as `src()`, if it was not already empty. Then you might say, they could have cleared the list, but hey, there are many other things that we can argue, if we go into the implementation details, can't we? ;)

Comment: @RohitJain: What I meant was that the method could replace existing elements in the target list, just as it currently does, but if the source list contains more elements than the target list, add the extra elements using `add` instead of `set`. That would make `Collections.copy` semantically a replacement of `clear` followed by `addAll`.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the implementation of `Collection.copy` method, it maintains the ***identical indices*** in **source** and **destination** Lists, after the copy operation.

To set an element at an index,  `set(int)` method should be used. `set(int)` method expects that the index is present in the destination list (unlike `add(Object)` which expands the list if there is no capacity).

Imagine if this method had used `add(Object)` while copying and the `dest` list had already had some elements, then the new elements (from `src`) would have got added at the end of `dest` list, ***breaking*** the **copy** contract (which means **same elements @ respective same indices**)

Hence the method throws exception if the destination list is not as long as source list

Comment: given that source is larger than dest, it's certainly _possibly_ to have implemented it in a way that used `set(index)` to replace existing elements and `add` to add further ones.

Comment: You are correct, but *conceptually* it is same as any other copy. Consider copying file from one drive to another. OS will not expand the destination drive to accommodate the source file, instead it complains.. may be we can think this like same way :)

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc explains the behavior. Please read the Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29

Answer (score -1):

You assume, a `List` size is mutable and `Collections.copy()` does not assume this to theoretically broaden the purpose of this class to all classes implementing the `List` interface instead of the mutable ones only.

Comment: Any exception regarding exceeding the capacity of a fixed-sized collection could be handled by _that collection_.  This utility method doesn't need to enforce it. The fact is, _it does_, but the OP is questioning why - this answer doesn't provide the reasoning he seeks.

Comment: You are inverting the problem, the utility method does not enforce anything concerning mutability, it rather states, that the collection to be copied into is at least as big as the source collection - if the utility method would demand that a collection is mutable, it would enforce something.

Comment: _You_ brought up mutability as the reason, not me. :)

Comment: No, the OP assumed the collection size of all classes implementing lists are to be seen as mutable by the method.

Comment: If that didn't hold, and `add` would fail, then that exception _could_ be thrown by the destination list when the operation that caused the size to need to be increased occurred - it need not be enforced by the utility method.

Comment: Yes, and either one does this implicitly (if the collection is smaller, call add, otherwise call set) or it bloats the code, Javadoc and error checking code without any additional features. Sometimes one should entrust in software developers to be able to read the API and stick to the contracts of it.